# Why on assigning fields in structures in C I get rubbish characters?

Tags: mysql, c, arrays, pointers, memory

**PREFACE**

Hello,

I'm debugging a piece of code in C that is driving me crazy since one hour. I suspect that the ever-confusing concept of pointers is what kills me here. Consider the following:

```
int getStatementsByScopId(MYSQL* con, int scopId, Statement* statements){
    char query[200] = "SELECT * FROM Statement";
    char whereClause[100]; 
    sprintf(whereClause, " WHERE scopId=%d", scopId);
    strcat(query, whereClause);
    if (mysql_query(con, query)){
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if (result == NULL){
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int i, j = 0, k, l;
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {           
        statements[j].domain = row[1];
        statements[j].name = row[2];
        statements[j].schedule = row[3];        
        char* statementId = row[0];     
        Access accesses[20];
-->     statements[j].accessCount = getAccessesByStatementId(con, statementId, accesses);           
        for(i = 0; i < statements[j].accessCount; i++){         
            statements[j].accesses[i] = accesses[i];
        }
        for (k = 0; k < statements[j].accessCount; k++){
            printf("%s\n", statements[j].accesses[k].kind);
            printf("%s\n", statements[j].accesses[k].relation);//WORKS
        }
        j++;
    }
    for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        for(l = 0; l < statements[k].accessCount; l++){
            printf("%s\n", statements[k].accesses[l].kind);
            printf("%s\n", statements[k].accesses[l].relation);
        }       
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
    return j;
}
```

In the `while` loop, I'm iterating over the results of `MySQL` query, and assign them to consecutive entries of the `statements` array. It is passed to the function as a static, 20-element array `Statement statements[20]`. I'm also assigning another array of structures to each `Statement` entry, of type `Access`. The access array is filled up by function `getAccessesByStatementId`, called at line marked by arrow (it takes the array to fill as an argument).

Here are the definitions of the structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char* kind;
    char* relation;
}Access;

typedef struct {
    char* domain;
    char* name;
    char* schedule;
    Access accesses[20];
    int accessCount;
}Statement;
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The values appear to be assigned correctly if I print them out inside the `while` loop (marked by `\\WORKS` comment). Which (I could be wrong) means that the problem does *not* lie in the `getAccessesByStatementId` function. I am also sure, that the results returned by the DB interface are 100% correct. However, if I try to do the same just before function exit (outside the `while` loop), I receive rubbish, random characters, which means that the some (or all) entries result in undefined behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement struct contains pointers to memory allocated by other code. The function mysql_free_result(result) frees that allocated memory. You should copy the results to your own storage before calling it.

Comment: Okay, but the loop printing erroneous results is called *before* the `mysql_free_result` statement.

Comment: You would need to show the code for mysql_fetch_row() and getAccessesByStatementId() to see what is happening to those pointers. Inside the while loop, try printing the values for statements[m] for m=0...j and you might find that the values for m<j are now garbage, since you did not COPY the value into your struct, but merely POINT to memory that may have gone out of scope.

Comment: So using `strcpy` instead could help?

Comment: strcpy() is a good start. You'll need to create space to store them yourself. You might change your sturct to have character arrays instead of pointers. Then copy to them. I believe the results from mysql are zero terminated strings. strcpy requires a zero terminated input string.

Comment: I rewrote structs to have statically allocated arrays for now (I know it should be dynamic, but temporarily it's fine), and copied using `strcpy`. That worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to leave space for the termination character on strings.